Expo Router - Transition back to screen with large title header is inconsistent with native behavior
I am trying to replicate the animation of the Contacts app on iOS, with a root screen with a large title header.
Using Expo Router, when I go back to the root screen, the animation goes back as if the header was small, and then "jumps" to being large again.
It's easier to show than to describe:

Any guidance on how to implement it correctly?
Thanks in advance!
